# Show a dropdown if certain conditions are met using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show my dropdown if a certain condition is met:

```
let managePermissionButton = () => {
    window.alert("->-> " + props.user.name)
    props.user.permissions.map((permission) => {
        if (permission.name === permissions) {
            window.alert("Im in")
            return <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Manage Permissions
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item"><Link className='nav-link' to='/addPermission'>Manage Permissions From Group</Link></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"><Link className='nav-link' to='/excludePermission'>Exclude Permission From User</Link></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    })
}
```

The "Im in" alert appears on screen when my code enters on my if statement, but is does not render my dropdown and I don´t know why.

Here is my rendering:

```
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <Link className='nav-link' to='/home'>Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                        <Link className='nav-link' to='/customers'>Customers</Link>
                    </li>
                    {managePermissionButton()}
                </ul>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => onClick(props)} class="btn btn-default btn-circle">Logout</button>{}
            </nav>
        </ul>
    </div>

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a return statement before props.user.permissions.map((permission)

```
let managePermissionButton = () => {
window.alert("->-> " + props.user.name)
return props.user.permissions.map((permission) => {
    if (permission.name === permissions) {
        window.alert("Im in")
        return <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Manage Permissions
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item"><Link className='nav-link' to='/addPermission'>Manage Permissions From Group</Link></a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item"><Link className='nav-link' to='/excludePermission'>Exclude Permission From User</Link></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
})
```

}